# Is there an SQL-like feature in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to connect to Google Spreadsheet in GAS using SQL-type queries?  If so, any working samples?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_jdbc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, there are two options.

1) You can have a SQL Database and connect to it using the Jdbc Service ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_jdbc ).

2) The other option, which I've used once earlier, is by making use of the QUERY() function. You can set the formula on a cell to the SQL like query and then read the subsequent cells. 
( https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882 ).

Update after Google I/O 2012:
As you might have already noticed, Google possibly heard you and introduced ScriptDB which is better than the two options mentioned

Comment: 2. is cool.  It's probably useful to my efforts as I'm working on GAS using Spreadsheets as database.

BigQuery is great but it's paid API and probably overkill.  Maybe in the future.

Thanks for the answer Srik.

Answer (score 0):

You can also used the "Structured Query" parameters available in the Spreadsheets API to make calls like: `&sq=filter:7` where filter is the name of your column and you want to return the results of any row where the value in that column is 7.  See the List Feed section of the Spreadsheet API.

Comment: The examples in the document are in three forms (Protocol, Java and .NET).  Which one is suitable to be used in Google Apps Script? Any working example we can take a look at?  Thanks.